# Javascript works Internally but Not Externally

Tags: javascript, html

The js code seems to be working when I place inside the HTML code, but doesn't work when I place it externally can someone please explain why? When placed externally I placed the script tag before the `</body>` Here's the HTML code, `JS` Code is a simple draggable div

> HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="main-view">
                <h1>Hello Welcome to the Site</h1>
                <div id="dxy">  <!--Draggable -->
                    <p>Hello Drag me Around!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> JS

```
window.onload = addListeners();

function addListeners(){
    document.getElementById('dxy').addEventListener('mousedown',mouseDown,false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup',mouseUp,false);
}

function mouseUp(){
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove',divMove,true);
}

function mouseDown(e){
    window.addEventListener('mousemove',divMove,true);
}

function divMove(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('dxy');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    div.style.left = e.clientX = 'px';
}
```

Comment: You will have to debug this yourself. Open the browser's JavaScript console. Do you see any error messages there? If not, then open the console's network tab. Has the JS file loaded correctly?

Comment: Doesn't `window.onload` want a function?  I believe that above you are assigning it to `undefined` (the return value of `addListeners()`).

Comment: well i did, but when I was debugging I tried all possible places

Comment: As @DavinTryon said, your line `window.onload = addListeners()` is executing the function `addListeners()` immidiately, not on window load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = addListeners();
```

needs to be

```
window.onload = addListeners;
```